# When does Area 51 proposal start to be advertised on the right-hand panel?

Tags: support, area-51, sidebar

[Area51 proposals are being advertised now all over the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208988/226001) doesn't seem to answer this question. For instance, I recollect that I first saw 'Economics Q&A', under which the Commitment rate ensues <s>ensued underneath by the Commitment rate</s>, while it was around 80% committed? I now see the promotions for 'Coffee Q&A', and recollect that they emerged also at the approximate 80% rate?

Comment: I think it is just random...

Comment: My impression is that a proposal gets advertised when it's pretty close to full commitment.

Comment: @Fund I saw http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64009/entertainment-lighting several times in the sidebar...

Comment: The answer there hints that it's done manually, by a dev: *...that we think deserves a little extra help*.