# Effect of right-hand panel adverts, on Area 51 Proposal Commitment Rates

Tags: discussion, area-51

In conjunction with [my other related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246901/226001), my curiosity motivates me to ask about the correlation between advertisement on the right-hand panel on commitment rates. For Economics SE, for example, I recollect that the Commitment rate increased sharply after the start of advertisements, to a rate never attained before. In fact, does anyone know how to obtain this data?

Comment: What about the effect of people promoting in their usernames? :)

Comment: @Scimonster: Supernal question indeed! Would you like to question anew about that, seeing as you mooted it first?

Comment: I don't think there's enough data to go on. You're probably the only one. :P

Comment: @Scimonster That's unfortunate, but let us both try to remember this idea, should more data be available?